# reload chrome extension on background using setInterval

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

says I have a rss reader extension, so far is when the user clicked on the browser action icon, my front end trigger the ajax to get the latest update. But how to auto update in the background? like every 5 min.

My concern is the performances issue if I use js setInterval function.

Answer (score 0):

*What performance issues?* Seriously, one 5-minute interval is not going to take much.

I have a couple of notifier-type extensions that use intervals to fetch data, and it's absolutely fine to do so.

If you're *really* concerned, you can switch to using [Event Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) (that will unload themselves to save resources) and use a dedicated [`chrome.alarms` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms).

Do read the documentation carefully, as [adapting your extension to an Event Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#transition) is not so trivial. And the potential gain - I don't see it in this scenario.